# VBA and SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel, vba

I'm new to all coding, I'm looking to update a SQL table, using VBA.
There are 4 columns that need to be updated, and then 4 other columns where to put the new data- so they link up to each other for example A and E link. A is where I want the most updated version of the data and E is where you put it in. I have another column where the user will mark an 'x' if they want these columns updated. I've got the beginning all sorted, connecting it to SQL its just the actual update part I'm stuck with...

So where the Upload Indicator is marked with an x then those columns should be updated, if there is no x just leave them as they are.

```
    'SQL update from four check columns from E-H
    'Set Value from "Check Column"
    'Where UpdateIndicator sht.Cells(Row,15) = "x"




 sSQL = "Update  [table].[dbo].[]"
 Set Check_titles= titles
 Set Check_ratings= ratings
 Set Check_star= star
 Set Check_location= location

 Where "Update Indicator" = x
```

Ive had to change a lot for an example as its confidential, so makes it slightly harder to explain

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you have an id value in your table?

Comment: Theres numerous other columns, such as the date and the name of the products that all the updates are about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to iterate through your cells in excel, and create an update statement for each row. Something like

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim sql As String

Do Until Cells(n,1) = ""
    If Cells(n,5) = "x"
        sql = "Update [dbo].[MyTable] SET "
        sql = sql + "Check_titles = '" + Cells(n, 2) + "',"
        sql = sql + "Check_ratings = '" + Cell(n, 3) + "',"
        sql = sql + "Check_star = '" + Cells(n, 4) + "',"
        sql = sql + "Check_location = '" + Cells(n, 5) + "'"
        sql = sql + " WHERE Id = " + Cells(n,1) 'Assumes unique id in col 1 
        MyConn.Execute(sql)
    End If
Loop
```

Where `MyConn` is your MySql connection and `n` represents the row number and substitute the column numbers for the correct values for the column names.